# How to get all products from Amazon's Product Advertising API with a single item search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, soap, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon's [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html). When I'm searching products by keyword from an item search operation I get only 10 results, is there any way to get all result in one single call?

Answer (score 2):

No - [Paging Through Results](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingThroughResults.html) explains some of the details:

> It is possible to create a request that returns many thousands of
>   items in a response. This is problematic for several reasons.
>   Returning all of the item attributes for those items would
>   dramatically impact the performance of Product Advertising API in a
>   negative way. Also, posting a thousand responses on a web page is
>   impractical.
>
> ...
>
> This example shows that 9729 items matched the search criteria. Also,
>   it shows that those results are on 973 (~9729/10) pages. You might try
>   putting in an ItemPage value over 10. If you do, Product Advertising
>   API returns the following error.
>
> ...
>
> So, how do you get that 973rd page? You cannot. A better approach is
>   to submit a new request that is more targeted and yields fewer items
>   in the response.

Comment: Note that the APi currently limits even the amount of pages you can get to 1-5 for ALL and 1-10 for other itemSearches. So don't ask for page 11  if you decided to do pagination requests.